# "From 10 to 20 March 2020" i need this date format from two dates

Tags: php, laravel

I have a start date and end date.

From those dates i need to print the dates in the below formats.For example:

- Start Date:10/03/2020
- End Date:20/03/2020

Needed Format :

- From 10 to 20 March 2020

```
public function EventPromo($id){
    $event=events::where('id',$id)->with('Organization')->get();
    return view('participants.preview',compact('event'));
}
```

From this i only get startdate format. I need to combine both start and end date.

In laravel blade:

```
{{ date('l jS \\of F Y ', strtotime($event[0]->startDate)) }}
```

[enter image description here][count down of dates]
form this start and end date i need to show how many days,hours,mins,sec for the event has to come and near.

```
<section class="section-swiper-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-lg-center countdown-container">
            <div class="" data-end-time="2020-03-10T00:00:00-03:00">
                <div class="countdown-member">
                    <span id="countdown-days" class="countdown-member-number">0</span>
                    <span id="countdown-days-label" class="countdown-member-label">Dias</span>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-member">
                    <span id="countdown-hours" class="countdown-member-number">0</span>
                    <span id="countdown-hours-label" class="countdown-member-label">Horas</span>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-member">
                    <span id="countdown-minutes" class="countdown-member-number">0</span>
                    <span class="countdown-member-label">Min</span>
                </div>
                <div class="countdown-member">
                    <span id="countdown-seconds" class="countdown-member-number">0</span>
                    <span class="countdown-member-label">Seg</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i dont know how to combine two dates to get this "From 10 to 20 March 2020"

Comment: i have startdate and enddate that are retriving from db

Comment: Additionally, what would the display be if months differ? Years too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will always have it in same month:

```
From {{ date('j', strtotime($event[0]->startDate)) }} 
to  {{ date('j', strtotime($event[0]->endDate)) }} 
    {{ date('F Y', strtotime($event[0]->endDate)) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the cleanest solution would be to ensure laravel knows which fields are date fields.

You can use date mutators for this: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

If you go to the model which contains the start_date and end_date, you can add:

Your model:

```
protected $dates = [
    'start_date',
    'end_date',
];
```

Now your `$model->start_date` and `$model->end_date` are both 'Carbon' classes.

Then, you can use an accessor(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

Your model:

```
function getFormattedRuntimeAttribute()
{
    $start_day = $this->start_date->format('j');
    $end_day = $this->end_date->format('j');
    $end_month = $this->end_date->format('F');
    return "from $start_day to $end_day $end_month";
}
```

Date-letters explained: https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/func_date_date.asp

Then in blade, you can use the model like so:

```
{{ $model->formatted_runtime }}
```

This should output something like: 'from 1 to 10 march'

Please not that this is fun when both start and end-date are in same month. Otherwise you will show the wrong start-date.

You could upgrade it to:

```
function getFormattedRuntimeAttribute()
{
    $start_day = $this->start_date->format('j');
    $start_month = $this->start_date->format('F');
    $end_day = $this->end_date->format('j');
    $end_month = $this->end_date->format('F');
    $start_month =  ($start_month == $end_month) ? '' : ' '.$start_month;
    return "from $start_day$start_month to $end_day $end_month";
}
```

I hope this helps :)